# Print instruction changes within PDF when printing via CUPS

Tags: pdf, cups

I can't seem to figure out if it is possible to print a multi page PDF via CUPS where I select different options at different points of the PDF.  Is anyone able to confirm whether this is possible and how?  I plan to communicate with CUPS via [api](https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html#submitting-a-print-job).

> e.g. Pages:
>
> Page 1 . Colour, Headed Paper, Portrait
>
> Pages 2 - 10 . B&W, Plain Paper, Portrait
>
> Page 11 . B&W, Plain Paper, Landscape

I know that I can control these options for a PDF in its entirety, an example of this is [here](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html)

The only way I can see of doing this is to split the PDF into three parts and print them separately but that would end up as three jobs going to the printer meaning that they could end up with a random print (from someone else depending on timing) between them.

If this is the only way, is there a way to capture the output and combine them to one file which then gets sent to the printer?